# Does PHP feature short hand syntax for objects?

Tags: php, object

In javascript you can easily create objects and Arrays like so:

```
var aObject = { foo:'bla', bar:2 };
var anArray = ['foo', 'bar', 2];
```

Are similar things possible in PHP?
I know that you can easily create an array using the array function, that hardly is more work then the javascript syntax, but is there a similar syntax for creating objects? Or should I just use associative arrays?

```
$anArray = array('foo', 'bar', 2);
$anObjectLikeAssociativeArray = array('foo'=>'bla',
                                      'bar'=>2);
```

So to summarize:
Does PHP have javascript like object creation or should I just use associative arrays?

Comment: Not that I'm aware.. And why would you want to? Javascript is so limited in comparison? Objects should be described properly, and with scope and hinting, etc.

Comment: any chance you can change the accepted answer on this one? the answer to this question has changed in the last 6 years. :)

Comment: *shorthand is always one word though.

Comment: I came here looking for "PHPON" (PHP object notation), which would be a PHP equivalent of JSON, and which I would find handy. Apparently it doesn't exist. Anyway, I found that using `var_export($var)` returns what I needed, even if it's not the most compact form. So this may be off-topic, sorry, but in case it's useful to someone... I'm leaving this comment. Feel free to tell me or downgrade me or ask me to delete this if it's a bad comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644870/php-object-literal)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

For simple objects, you can use the associative array syntax and casting to get an object:

```
<?php
$obj = (object)array('foo' => 'bar');
echo $obj->foo; // yields "bar"
```

But looking at that you can easily see how useless it is (you would just leave it as an associative array if your structure was that simple).

Comment: Yeah, in that case I might just as well use a normal associative array.

Comment: working with objects is easier because if you have an intricate structure of objects and arrays and maps you can go from something like this `$group["id123abc"]["people"][0]["name"]` to this `$group["id123abc"]->people[0]->name`. This makes it easier to grasp the difference between an array, a map and an object or structure

Answer (score 45):

There was a [proposal to implement this array syntax](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/shortsyntaxforarrays). <del>But it was declined.</del>

---

**Update**    The shortened syntax for arrays has been rediscussed, accepted, and is now on the [way be released with PHP 5.4](https://wiki.php.net/todo/php54).

But there still is no shorthand for objects. You will probably need to explicitly cast to *object*:

```
$obj = (object) ['foo'=>'bla', 'bar'=>2];
```

Comment: This has been implemented in PHP 5.4.

Comment: I wonder if a shorthand notation for objects will ever be implemented? I use stdClasses all the time, but they feel so awkward compared to javascript object literals.

Comment: This method doesn't work in class variable declaration. For example `protected $test = (object) ['prop'=>'val'];` doesn't work.

Comment: Yep, this method now works, but still it sure would be nice to have `$obj = {'foo'=>'bla'}`

Comment: There's an [inactive RFC from 2011](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/objectarrayliterals) for the shorthand object syntax.

Answer (score 11):

As of PHP 5.4, you can do this:

```
$array = ['foo'=>'bla', 'bar'=>2];
```

It's not much shorter, but you'll appreciate it if you need to use a lot of hard coded nested arrays (which isn't altogether uncommon).

If you want an object, you would still need to cast each array:

```
$object = (object) ['foo'=>'bla', 'bar'=>2];
```

Answer (score 10):

According to the new PHP syntaxes,

You can use

```
$array = [1,2,3];
```

And for associative arrays

```
$array = ['name'=>'Sanket','age'=>22];
```

For objects you can typecast the array to object

```
$object = (object)['name'=>'Sanket','age'=>22];
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no object shorthand in PHP, but you can use Javascript's exact syntax, provided you use the [json_encode](http://us.php.net/json_encode) and [json_decode](http://us.php.net/json_decode) functions.

Comment: Interesting idea, though doesn't that delay parsing until run-time? When would this have an advantage over casting an array with `(object)`?

Answer (score 2):

The method provided by crescentfresh works very well but I had a problem appending more properties to the object. to get around this problem I implemented the spl ArrayObject.

```
class ObjectParameter extends ArrayObject  {
     public function  __set($name,  $value) {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }

    public function  __get($name) {
      return $this[$name];
    }
}

//creating a new Array object
$objParam = new ObjectParameter;
//adding properties
$objParam->strName = "foo";
//print name
printf($objParam->strName);
//add another property
$objParam->strUser = "bar";
```

There is a lot you can do with this approach to make it easy for you to create objects even from arrays, hope this helps .

Answer (score 1):

Like the json_decode idea, wrote this:

```
function a($json) {
 return json_decode($json, true); //turn true to false to use objets instead of associative arrays
}

//EXAMPLE
$cat = 'meow';

$array = a('{"value1":"Tester", 
  "value2":"'.$cat.'", 
  "value3":{"valueX":"Hi"}}');

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score -1):

Another json_decode approach. This feels like a lot of runtime overhead just to make coding simpler, but I guess that's what languages do. The $str argument is actually less JSON and more straight Javascript (shorter). The $assoc argument is a passthrough to the json_decode $assoicative argument.

```
function obj( $str, $assoc=null ) {

    $o = '';

    foreach( explode( ',', $str ) AS $v ) {
        $s  = explode( ':', trim( $v ) );
        $o .= '"' . implode( '":"', $s ) . '",';
    }

    return json_decode( '{' . trim( $o, ',' ) . '}', $assoc );
}

// example
$array  = obj( "val1:value 1,val2:value 2", 1 );
$object = obj( "val1:value 1,val2:value 2", 0 );

print_r( $array );

// returns
Array
(
    [val1] => value 1
    [val2] => value 2
)

print_r( $object );

stdClass Object
(
    [val1] => value 1
    [val2] => value 2
)
```

Comment: Or just `$object = new class{var $val1 = "value 1"; var $val2 = "value 2";};`