# PHP object literal

Tags: php, object, literals, object-literal

In PHP, I can specify array literals quite easily:

```
array(
    array("name" => "John", "hobby" => "hiking"),
    array("name" => "Jane", "hobby" => "dancing"),
    ...
)
```

But what if I want array of objects? How can I specify object literal in PHP?
I.e. in javascript it would be:

```
[
    {name: "John", hobby: "hiking"},
    {name: "Jane", hobby: "dancing"}
]
```

Comment: There is no object literal in PHP.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, I don't understand your comment. JS objects is associative arrays, but PHP associative arrays are not objects. Also  PHP is not ECMAScript language, and PHP is not even JS.

Comment: @DmitryZorin I see. I thought that PHP associative arrays *are* objects (like in JavaScript).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I understand what you are saying but what you must understand is how the two different langauges are interpreted, which is very different.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I think TMS was showing how to do it in JavaScript as an illustration.  So the question is "how do I do the same in PHP?"

Answer (score 99, accepted):

As BoltClock mentioned there is no object literal in PHP however you can do this by simply type casting the arrays to objects:

```
$testArray = array(
    (object)array("name" => "John", "hobby" => "hiking"),
    (object)array("name" => "Jane", "hobby" => "dancing")
);

echo "Person 1 Name: ".$testArray[0]->name;
echo "Person 2 Hobby: ".$testArray[1]->hobby;
```

Comment: Do note that objects are always passed by reference, arrays are not.  So changing an attribute of an object changes it everywhere the object has been assigned.  This is not the case for arrays; they remain independent.

Comment: @GregoryCosmoHaun Objects are not passed by reference. They are passed by a numeric value called object identifier. Which allows object accessors to find the actual object.

Comment: @Rain What is the difference? An "object identifier" that refers to a particular object is a reference to the object, isn't it?

Comment: @Stack-Underflow You can see how these techniques are different here https://3v4l.org/hkOcA

Comment: @Rain the example you linked has a typo that obscures what you were trying to show. Here's a corrected version: https://3v4l.org/njjm6.

Comment: @DavidP.Caldwell,@Rain The examnple clearly shows that objects are passed by reference. You are confusing passing an object by reference with passing a reference to a variable. This works like in practically other language, calling a reference an "identifier" might be a PHP quirk, but it does not change that it is pass by reference.

Answer (score 69):

As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax:

```
$json = [
    (object) ['name' => 'John', 'hobby' => 'hiking'],
    (object) ['name' => 'Jane', 'hobby' => 'dancing'],
];
```

Comment: excelent, this makes for a lot cleaner scripts

Answer (score 16):

As others have noted, there is no object literal in PHP, but you can "fake" it by casting an array to an object.

With PHP 5.4, this is even more concise, because [arrays can be declared with square brackets](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).  For example:

```
$obj = (object)[
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];
```

This would give you an object with "foo" and "bar" properties.  However, I don't think this really provides much advantage over using associative arrays.  It's just a syntax difference.

Consider embracing the uniqueness and "flavor" of all the languages you use.  In JavaScript, object literals are all over the place.  In PHP, associative arrays are functionally the same as JavaScript object literals, are easy to create, and are well understood by other PHP programmers.  I think you're better off embracing this "flavor" than trying to make it feel like JavaScript's object literal syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Another way would be to use the [`__set_state()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.set-state) magic method:

```
$object = stdClass::__set_state (array (
    'height'   => -10924,
    'color'    => 'purple',
    'happy'    => false,
    'video-yt' => 'AgcnU74Ld8Q'
));
```

[Some more on the __set_state() method, where is it coming from and how is it supposed to be used.](http://www.thoughtlabs.com/2008/02/02/phps-mystical-__set_state-method/)

Comment: -1, This would be cool if it worked. However, `stdClass` does not have a defined `__set_state` method.

Answer (score 4):

Although casting as an (object) works fine on a single hierarchical level, it doesn't go deep. In other words, if we want objects at every level, we'd have to do something like:

```
$foods = (object)[
  "fruits" => (object)["apple" => 1, "banana" => 2, "cherry" => 3],
  "vegetables" => (object)["asparagus" => 4, "broccoli" => 5, "carrot" => 6]
];
```

However, instead of doing multiple casting as objects, we can wrap the whole thing in a json_encode and json_decode like this:

```
$foods = json_decode(json_encode([
  "fruits" => ["apple" => 1, "banana" => 2, "cherry" => 3],
  "vegetables" => ["asparagus" => 4, "broccoli" => 5, "carrot" => 6]
]));
```

That makes sure it's an object at the deepest level.

To answer klewis, you can then access this like:

```
echo $foods->vegetables->broccoli;
```

This example would output the number 5.

Comment: Nice solutions, can you provide a simple example with your second option in referencing the value of broccoli in an echo statement?

Comment: `<?php

    $foods = json_decode(json_encode([
      "fruits" => ["apple" => 1, "banana" => 2, "cherry" => 3],
      "vegetables" => ["asparagus" => 4, "broccoli" => 5, "carrot" => 6]
    ]));

    echo $foods->vegetables->broccoli;

?>`

should output the number 5

Comment: by far the best answer on this thread for thoughe coming from a javascript background and want either a single level or deep level approach.

Answer (score 2):

My way of ***JavaScript-style object literals in PHP*** is as follows:

First I create an associative array like this:

```
$test = array(
  'name' => "test",
  'exists' => true
);
```

Then I easily make it an object like this:

```
$test = (object)$test;
```

Now you can test it:

```
echo gettype($test); // "object"
echo $test->name; // "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you have ro create an instance before you can use a class. Of course you can put the instances into an array later.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to define modules in the object literal pattern "like JavaScript", you could do something like this:

```
$object = (object) [
    'config' => (object) [
        'username' => 'Rob Bennet',
        'email' => 'rob@madebyhoundstooth.com'
    ],

    'hello' => function() use(&$object) {
        return "Hello " . $object->config->username . ". ";
    },

    'emailDisplay' => function() use(&$object) {
        return "Your email address is " . $object->config->email;
    },

    'init' => function($options) use(&$object) {
        $object->config = $options;
        $doUsername = $object->hello;
        $doEmail = $object->emailDisplay;
        return $doUsername() . $doEmail();
    }
];

$sayMyInfo = $object->init;

echo $sayMyInfo((object) [
    'username' => 'Logan',
        'email' => 'wolverine@xmen.com'
]);
```

In this type of modular scenario, I usually opt for the [facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), I just like writing my calls thusly:

```
Module::action()->item;
```

or

```
Post::get()->title;
```

Neither of these patterns make it easy (or even possible sometimes) for testing. But this is just proof of concept. Technically, "no" there is no Object Literal in PHP, but if you're used to JavaScript syntax (which I am more so than PHP), you can fake it and do this. As you can see, it's a lot messier in PHP than in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If the `json_decode(json_encode( $array ))` isn't good for you, then you can use some similar functions like these. Which one is faster, I don't know.

```
function deep_cast_object( $o ){
  return deep_cast_object_ref( $o );
}

function deep_cast_object_ref( & $o ){

  if( is_array( $o ))
    $o = (object)$o;

  if( is_object( $o ))
    foreach( $o as & $v )
      deep_cast_object_ref( $v );

  return $o;
}

$obj = deep_cast_object(array(
  'Fractal' => array(
    'of'    => array(
      'bad' => 'design',
    ),
  ),
));

var_dump( $obj );
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution

```
$obj = json_decode('{"ape":"kwyjibo"}');
echo $obj->ape;

[output:]
kwyjibo
```

Then you can wrap it into a function and return your literal object

```
$obj = literal_object(['key1','val1','key2','val2']);
```